# Envira gallery not showing images

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, gallery, image-gallery

I'm using the Envira Gallery wordpress plugin but the images are not shown in the posts. I can see them in the inspector and if i click the link, the image opens in another tab. The images are however only 1px heigh and 20 px wide, no matter what i do - meaning they aren't really there.

My css and .js loads okay, so no problem there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your CSS and JS code

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you input without actual code, although it is on Wordpress.

Find out what class holds your images, as you mentioned they are:

```
height: 1px;
width: 20px;
```

For example, if your class name is **.enviraImage** just add:

```
.enviraImage {
  height: 120px !important;
  width: 80px !important;
}
```

One other thing you can try is adding z-index:

```
.enviraImage {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#envira-gallery-"your gallery id here" {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

gallery id is found under the 'Envira code' tab on main page of plugin